# How to pass values from an asp.net child page to the parent page

Tags: c#, asp.net, return-value, parent-child, popupwindow

I have two web pages, `Page1` and `Page2`, which can both open the same child popup page.

If the parent page is `Page1` I want certain input from the Child page to returned to the parent page and if the parent page is `Page2` I want other information to be returned.

I do identify who is the parent page and how do I return the input to it and have it show in the proper text box or DroDownList?

I tried using `Request.UrlReferrer` putting results in a string variable and I got an error 'object not set to an instance'.

Comment: Did you try to use javascript or is not an option for you?

Comment: @Tariqulazam I'm not strong on javascript, but if I'm given details I'm willing to try.

Comment: The answer by Imran Rizvi should help.

Answer (score 3):

As both the pages can be parent , write the a javascript function that works as receiver on both the page and write code in it as per your requirement.

e.g.

javascript on Parent page:

```
SetDataFromPopup(data)
{
    document.getElementById('TextBox1ClientId').value = data;
}
```

On popup write the following line

```
window.opener.SetDataFromPopup(data);
```

this should be called on the event where you want to pass the data e.g. suppose you have a button on client click of it you want to pass the data , the code should look like:

```
<input id="btnSave" type="submit" onclick="window.opener.SetDataFromPopup(data);" >Save</input>
```

Comment: Where would I put that line in the popup? As a function?

Comment: on the event where you want to pass the value e.g. if you want to pass it on a button click you should write like <input id="btnSave" type="submit" onclick="window.opener.SetDataFromPopup(data);" >Save</input>     .   Edited my answer as well...

Comment: Can this be used to add to a DropDownList or an ajax toolkit ComboBox? How?

Comment: will that know to rerturn to Page1 and not to Page2? Thank you.

Comment: once you have the value you can add it to drop down list or combo box, I am sure these control allow you to add/change values through javascript or by manipulating DOM. check it out , i am not sure of exact syntex.

Comment: I am getting the following runtime error: SCRIPT5007: Unable to set value of the property 'value': object is null or undefined. I made the following function on the parent page :

Comment: you might have given the wrong client id of textbox. can you share the code?

Comment: The id is right this is the code: function SetDataFromPopup(email)
    {
        document.getElementById('txtCliContEmail').value = email;
    }

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11331/discussion-between-imran-rizvi-and-dov-miller)